# Dialplan execution order

Tags: asterisk, telephony

I have the following context in my asterisk dialplan.

```
[start-call]
exten => _X.,1,AGI(agi://localhost:4000)
exten => _X.,n,GotoIf($["${AGISTATUS}" = "FAILURE"]?redirect)
exten => _X.,1000(redirect),Hangup(31)    
exten => 900,n,Goto(start-call,${EXTEN},1)
exten => h,n,Hangup
```

I have an AGI app which connects the call and collects DTMF inputs, and set that number as the extension using the SET EXTENSION agi command (line 1). I set the AGISTATUS to FAILURE only when there is no DTMF input. If there is no input, I timeout, and hangup (line 3). But if 900 is entered I go back to start-call context and do some magic in the AGI application (line 4).

The problem is that, right now even if I enter 900 the call just gets hung up. And not from line 3 but the last line. So its skipping line 4 somehow. If I move the 900 extension (line 4) before the one labelled **redirect** (line 3), it works.

I thought asterisk increments the '**n**' priority automatically, and would expect this to work in the order listed above. Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialplan must be consecutive. Ext 1000 is never hit - hence asterisk falls through to the h exten.

Comment: But isn't the priority 'n' supposed to order it automatically? Even if 1000 isn't hit, shouldn't asterisk move to the next priority 'n' line?

Comment: It would seem that dialplan MUS be consecutive. Weird, I know. But this is Asterisk after all...

Comment: see my answer to understand why it must be "consecutive". in fact, it must not but only consecutive will give you the expected result.

Answer (score 5):

`n` iterates automatically - it adds 1 to the *previous* priority. This is also why you have to initialize the incrementor with priority 1 in the first line.

When you put priority 1000 somewhere in the middle (which is totally valid) the next line with `n` will add 1 to this, resulting in priority 1001 - which is never hit as already explained by others.

Your dialplan can be read like below:

```
[start-call]
exten => _X.,1,AGI(agi://localhost:4000)
exten => _X.,2,GotoIf($["${AGISTATUS}" = "FAILURE"]?redirect)
exten => _X.,1000(redirect),Hangup(31)    
exten => 900,1001,Something()                                          ; not 3!
exten => h,1,Hangup
```

To fix this you must either reorder your extensions as explained by others or use the `+` operator for priorities:

```
[start-call]
exten => _X.,1,AGI(agi://localhost:4000)                               ; 1
exten => _X.,n,GotoIf($["${AGISTATUS}" = "FAILURE"]?redirect)          ; 2
exten => _X.,n+1000(redirect),Hangup(31)                               ; 1002
exten => 900,n,Something()                                             ; 3
exten => h,1,Hangup
```

By the way, you can also use text labels as extensions, which will make your dialplans more readable:

```
[start-call]
exten => _X.,1,AGI(agi://localhost:4000)                               ; 1
exten => _X.,n,GotoIf($["${AGISTATUS}" = "FAILURE"]?agi_failure,1)     ; 2
exten => 900,n,Something()                                             ; 3

exten => agi_failure,1,DoSomething()
exten => agi_failure,n,DoEvenMore()

exten => h,1,Hangup
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the dialplan must be consecutive, and once you start the "n" series you need to stick with it.  I am assuming extension 900 is an example of the DTMF input -- this new extension must always start with a priority of 1.  The "h" extension must also start with a priority of 1

```
[start-call]
exten => _X.,1,AGI(agi://localhost:4000)
exten => _X.,n,GotoIf($["${AGISTATUS}" = "FAILURE"]?redirect)
exten => _X.,n,**if input received do something here**
exten => _X.,n(redirect),Hangup(31)    

exten => 900,1,Goto(start-call,${EXTEN},1)
exten => h,1,Hangup
```

Comment: actually, `exten => 900,1,Goto(start-call,${EXTEN},1)` will result in an infinite loop, a non-working call and many wasted CPU cycles. Substituting _X. with 900 for just a single priority is totally valid.